# How to fill cells dynamically based on the value of a cell? How to segregate values based on a particular cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, ms-office, excel-2007

Suppose, I have secured Marks for a particular subject which have 5 course Outcomes (each containing 2Marks--Total 10 marks for each subject).

I have the total marks obtained for all the students, but not the marks of each CO.
I want to fill the COs(Column B-F) based on the Column H(Total).

Example- A Student having total of 8 should have the value- 2,2,2,1,1 or 2,2,1,2,1, etc

Conditions-

1. All the cells should be filled in case of marks with >5
2. Each cell should have the value between 1 and 2. 0 in case when total is less than 5. As we don't have enough values to fill:

[image]

Previously, I used the `randbetween(1,2)` in Columns `B` to `E` (to get random values between `1` and `2`) and for Column `F`, `I` used the formula `=10-SUM(B6:E6)`

It works fine, but doesn't work well if the difference is more than 2(which violates our condition)

Answer (score 1):

With 2007 we need to refer to the cell in column A, so change that to an empty cell or text. Put this in B2 and copy over and down:

```
=IF(SUM($A2:A2)+6-COLUMN(A$1)>=$H2,1,IF($H2/(6-COLUMN(A$1))>=2,2,RANDBETWEEN(1,2)))
```

[image]

with Office 365 we do not need Column A to be blank or text as we no longer need to refer to it:

```
=LET(
    sm,H2,
    rng,B2:F2,
    clm,COLUMN(rng),
    {1,1,1,1,1}+ISNUMBER(MATCH(clm,TAKE(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1,100,MIN(clm),MAX(clm),TRUE),TRUE),,sm-5),0)))
```